# Dynamically catch exceptions in callback function

Tags: python

I'm writing a basic logging utility, and I want it to use a callback function, and then check for a list of exceptions that might have occurred.

I think the code will explain for itself.
I know the following example is not valid code, it is included for clarification.

```
    def Except(self, func, exceptions, *args, **kwargs):
        """Used for logging exceptions"""
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        for exception in exceptions: # Obviously this doesn't work.
            except exception as e:
                self.log(f"{e}", "error", 4)
```

However, **I am** surprised unpacking doesn't work.

```
    def Except(self, func, exceptions, *args, **kwargs):
        """Used for logging exceptions"""
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (*exceptions) as e:
            self.log(f"{e}", "error", 4)
```

Is there any way to dynamically catch exceptions with a callback function like this? I can't seem to find anything in the **[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)** about it.

Comment: You have to catch the most general exception (usually "Exception"), check if the actual exception is of a type in your list and react accordingly. If the exception isn't in the list it can be reraised with plain "raise" in the except-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to catch the general `Exception` exception, check if the actual exception belongs to the interesting exception classes and react accordingly.

This approach can also be used for a more individual reaction based on exception type. E. g. there could be a function assigned to each type which is called if the exception is of this type.

```
def Except(self, func, exceptions, *args, **kwargs):
    """Used for logging exceptions"""
    try:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        for ec in exceptions:
            if isinstance(e, ec):
                self.log(f"{e}", "error", 4)
                return
                
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `Except` class like this,

```
def Except(func, exceptions, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    except exceptions as e:
        print(f"{e}", "error")

def foo():
    l = [1]
    return l[1]
    
# Exception as tuple
exceptions = (TypeError, KeyError, IndexError)

Except(foo, exceptions)
```

Or, the most common approach catches the general exceptions.

```
try:
    foo()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{e}", "error")
```

Outputs:

```
list index out of range error
```